# Proposition to make gerrymandering obsolete

Tags: united-states, gerrymandering

Many problems in democratic representation stem from the fact that many citizen votes are merged into one representative vote. Gerrymandering is one of such problems. But, what if the representatives hold all the citizen votes? If Colorado has 8 representatives, then the total votes they hold would be the total voting pool of the state of Colorado, let's say 4.4 million. So, all representatives in the House of Commons would hold and vote with all the registered votes in the U.S.

To prevent gerrymandering a federal law needs to be introduced that would introduce this system, and instruct the states to incorporate it, and would fix the votes for those representatives that do not yet have this new system incorporated. So if Colorado did not distribute all 4.4 million votes to their representatives then the country would do it for them instead. On the House floor after voting we would see for instance 100 millions yea and 60 millions nay votes, instead of 300 yea and 135 nay, but that would be it.

Second part of the solution is the redistribution of votes. If one party candidate loses the election in their district, all the votes that they garnered would automatically be redistributed to all other winners from the same party in other districts. This puts parties at the advantage over independent candidates, but could also help create new parties, which would better represent their constituents. But no vote would be left behind.

How does this solve gerrymandering? Well, if after elections there is at least one representative left from the disenfranchised party, this one person would hold all the disenfranchised votes. All of them! This one person could become the most powerful representative from this state. I don't think the incumbent party would actually want that (unless it's their own plant). All the efforts put into gerrymandering would be for nothing, if not even counter-productive.

Can you find issues with this system?

The states could make a law that all the votes from the district go to the election winner, even those votes that they did not get. Or distributed to all winners, not just from the same party. These workarounds are anti-constitutional, because the voters are not properly represented. The federal law could even have provisions against it.

Comment: Closed? I ask "can you find issues with this system", not "do you like it". Come on. Is there something fundamentally wrong with this system or not?

Comment: Welcome aboard.  "What if" scenarios aren't a good fit for this site.  If you had asked about proposed voting methodologies that, even if not implemented, at least were coming from political scientists/voting system experts, then one could refer to what other experts had to say about such a proposal.  But that is not the case and site users generally frown on asking about "personal ideas and solutions".  Not least because it would basically boil to each answerer's opinion, with nothing to refer to back them up.  There are many other voting system questions around, take a look which ones worked

Comment: Well, I guess I would just have to win elections in existing country, change that country's system and see if it works for myself, without any expert to tell me about an obvious flaw in my plan (if there is any).

Comment: Possibly, but an additional complication is that you asked about the US, to fix an US issue, where your proposal would likely run afoul of its constitution before implementation.

Comment: The world does not want for a solution to gerrymandering. The most common one is called in its many forms, proportional representation. The barriers to adopting something along that lines are not that they would fail to solve gerrymandering, but that people with political power don't want to solve the problem of gerrymandering.

Comment: I believe the gerrymandering is the response to the Tyranny of the majority. I may have the solution for that too, but haven't worked out all the details. Alas, even if I had, I can't discuss it here apparently.

Comment: Arrow's theorem says you can't fix those problems all at the same time. If you don't know enough to check this, you are not providing any new solutions, as others already mention.

Comment: I have three comments on that. First, Arrow's theorem could only be mentioned in the context of the "Tyranny of the majority" problem, but I didn't speak about that here. Second, we should strive to work on the best achievable solution, even if this solution might not be perfect. Third, Arrow's theorem is applicable if you have only one decision to make or if voting process is independent between decisions. But if we aggregate decisions with votes then we reduce the possibility of dissatisfaction. This is part of my solution to the problem that I didn't speak about here.

Answer (score 1):

One major issue with this system is that you have *no idea who you are actually voting for*. If the candidate you cast a vote for loses their race, your vote is siphoned off to support some candidate who is impossible to identify beforehand. A vote is an endorsement of giving someone your political voice - it's a big problem to vote for Mrs. X, but find to find out after the fact that your political power was actually granted to Mr. Y instead. You are no longer voting for an individual, but acceding that anyone with a -D or -R next to their name is functionally equivalent, which isn't really true. A representative may find themselves "representing" people they have no relationship with whatsoever, with whom they do not agree, and who never intended to vote for or support them in any way. Imagine the scenario where a fringe candidate wins their election, while moderates lose in close races - it's hard to argue that the fringe candidate should become more powerful in such a scenario, and that people who voted for the failed moderate candidate are actually best represented by a fringe candidate in another district.

Comment: This federal redistribution is only a fix for those states who don't have proper law in place. I would imagine a proper state law would introduce a [single transferable vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote) system, to truly follow the spirit of "no vote left behind" idea.

Comment: Also, with STV the idea of districts becomes obsolete as well. There are no districts, there are only people.

Comment: Not entirely sure how much I'd agree with this. With the current loose party culture and two party system in the USA it'd certainly apply, but both of those are also the consequence of FPTP voting. Other countries which already have proportional voting tend to have much stricter parties as well as more options, and breaking the party line is both much less common and tends to carry more severe consequences. That said, how long it takes for party culture and composition to a proportional system would be hard to say, and could cause trouble in-between as parties reorganize and split.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, OP's system has a weird blend of transferable vote mechanisms mixed in with the proportional vote stuff, which could throw stuff off.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:**
>
> Proposition to make gerrymandering obsolete

Your solution making congressional districts like senators and subject to state wide votes would certainly fix the gerrymandering problem.  It however would introduce a different problem.  One where population centers in the state would control all the political support and more rural areas would cease to be represented at all.

Gerrymandering is a real problem.  To date the battles against it are being conducted through enforcing the voting rights act of 1965.  Imperfect but it has been effective.